# SQL - insert into QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)

Tags: t-sql

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(30), @Article varchar(16), @PartnerID int
set @DatabaseName = 'DEMO'
set @Article = 'Article1'
set @PartnerID = 1
INSERT INTO QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '.dbo.move(Article, Partner, Note)'
select @Article, @PartnerID, 'Note'
```

I have this and error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

I try:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(30), @Article varchar(16), @PartnerID int
set @DatabaseName = 'Demo'
set @Article = 'Article1'
set @PartnerID = 1
set @SQL = N'INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N'.dbo.move(Article, Partner, Note)'
+ N'select ' + @Article + N', ' + @PartnerID + N', '''Note''' '
exec @SQL
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Note'.

Comment: You can't `N'` a variable.

Comment: But I have exclude variable?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for this? Do you have a requirement that the table names are variable? A variable database is better handled with different connection strings.

Comment: I have cursor which make insert in few database on dependecy. So I need work on this way.

Comment: I have:
`SET @DatabaseName = CASE     WHEN @Owner = 'FS' then 'Demo'
WHEN @Owner = 'GS' then 'Demo1'
WHEN @Owner = 'FU' then 'Demo2'
WHEN @Owner = 'SS' then 'Demo3'
ELSE 'DEMOOO'
END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use dynamic SQL (which should be avoided if you have alternatives), it's still a good idea to use `sp_executesql` and parameters, and using `REPLACE` to construct statements rather than concatenation saves a lot of headaches debugging the proper escaping. In your example:

```
SET @SQL = REPLACE(
    'INSERT INTO $database.dbo.move(Article, Partner, Note) 
     VALUES (@Article, @Partner, ''Note'')', 
    '$database', QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
);
PRINT @SQL;  -- check what we've produced
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @stmt = @sql, 
    @params = N'@Article VARCHAR(16), @Partner INT', 
    @Article = @Article, @Partner = @PartnerID
;
```